# Apply high frequency rapid up and down movement at the muscle's current maximum stretch point

Tags: stretching, yoga, breathing

Introducing up and down vibration in muscle's current maximum stretch point is wrong right?
For a example what they doing in 2:23 upward, [Hot Yoga and CONTORTION, flexibility, Total Body Stretch - Gymnastics Exercises](https://youtu.be/ej1j2a3pVB4?t=143) [However there are 15k likes so 15k people think this is the right way of stretching ? or is that really the right way to do that? I need to verify ]
It may be okay for the hyper-flexible people but didn't do any research regarding that antinomy. They sound like hyper-flexible to me BTW.

As I researched many texts regarding flexibility, texts say that even introduce vibration is wrong, you still can relax and stretch again but very slowly while breathing. relax a little while breathing out and stretch back while breathing in. And need to pay the complete concentration on the stretch pain, so the neurons related to that muscle will create new synaptic connections[ not from Sanskrit book but from a yoga antimony book content].

Like, relax little very little while breathing out and stretch back more when breathing in. Breathing should not be suffered from hyperventilation conditions , it must be very slow controlled nose breath right? While breathing the yogi must concentrate on the pain so the brain will make more synaptic connections and made the muscles more stretched and stronger.

can you verify my understanding regarding the science of stretching?

Comment: Dude the title of the video is "Hot Yoga..." The 15k likes don't mean they think it is the right way of stretching, it means they liked looking at some ass. As far as research is concerned if I remember correctly, static slow stretching produced the best results over bounce stretching.

Comment: It’s yoga for a reason…I don’t see a point in “over-stretching” your muscles. You need a certain threshold for your myosin and actin to act favourably, and efficiently produce a stretch shortening cycle. This is just my take. But they might be doing PNF stretching. You can look that up. There are more than just static stretching for your muscles.

Comment: Probably I have to do more readings and research on bounce stretching and static slow stretching. As well as PNF stretching. It will take time and I'll come back anyway. Sorry just landed here with a computer science major.  Even I'm not somebody who completed a Yoga basic diploma course.

Comment: To be very clear, I know little to nothing about the current literature of stretching. I just remember reading something about static stretching out performing 3 other types a few years ago. By now that information may have been disproven.

Comment: What this is showing is called "ballistic stretching" in which you "bounce" the stretch beyond your physical limit. It's typically deemed unsafe for untrained individuals because you're literally forcing the muscle beyond what it's capable of doing. Experienced athletes *might* find some benefit as they're more resilient. I don't think there's much literature on them.

Comment: Side note.  A lot of likes on social media doesn't mean that the person is saying good or bad things.  It just means what they're saying is what people like hearing.

Comment: @DeeV absolutory true. Since the content is free and anybody can made content, it could be abused. Facebook is completely for politics , tik-tok is actually originally for learning, but now not safe for children. Only research gate linked-in are keeping their research disciplines. But hard to connect and find network at those places since too professional. Books are also like that, some kundalini yoga myths are well openly published in local language texts.